pywinusb mouse raw input capturing
I am trying to get the mouse raw data with pywinusb.
import pywinusb.hid as hid

def sample_handler(data):
    print("Received raw data")
    print(f"Data Type: {type(data)}, Data Length: {len(data)}")
    print("Raw data: {0}".format(data))

def find_mouse_device():
    all_hids = hid.HidDeviceFilter().get_devices()
    for device in all_hids:
        print(f"Device found: {device.product_name} (Vendor ID: {device.vendor_id}, Product ID: {device.product_id})")
        if 'mouse' in device.product_name.lower():
            return device
    return None

def main():
    mouse = find_mouse_device()

    if mouse:
        print(f"Mouse found: {mouse.product_name} (Vendor ID: {mouse.vendor_id}, Product ID: {mouse.product_id})")

        try:
            mouse.open()
            print("Device opened successfully.")
            mouse.set_raw_data_handler(sample_handler)
            print("Raw data handler set.")

            print("Listening for raw data... (Press Ctrl+C to stop)")

            try:
                while True:
                    pass
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print("Stopping...")
            finally:
                mouse.close()
                print("Device closed.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")
    else:
        print("No mouse found.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

This outputs this
Device found: Gaming Mouse G402 (Vendor ID: 1133, Product ID: 49278)
Mouse found: Gaming Mouse G402 (Vendor ID: 1133, Product ID: 49278)
Device opened successfully.
Raw data handler set.
Listening for raw data... (Press Ctrl+C to stop)
Stopping...
Device closed.

Which finds the rigth mouse, but it isnt capturing any data. I was also trying libusb and pyusb but I got the backend unavailable error.
